# Why isn't my image clickable in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hyperlink, image, clickable

Hoping someone can help me with this problem I'm having w/ IE. So the page I am working on has an image containing Facebook, Twitter and Youtube tabs.

[image]

All these tabs are clickable in most other browsers (Chrome/Safari/Firefox/Opera) except in Internet Explorer (7/8). I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, can anyone PLEASE help me?

HTML (edited):

```
<div id="head">
    .
    .
    .
    <div id="icons">
        <ul class="nav1">
            <li></li>
            <li><a id="facebook" rel="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a id="twitter" rel="_blank" href="https://twitter.com">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a id="youtube" rel="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com">&nbsp;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

CSS (edited):

```
#icons {
    position:absolute;
    top:44px;
    right:200px;
    z-index:9;
    float:left;
    /*width:105px;*/
    height:35px;
    /*background:url(/images/sprite_header_icons.png) no-repeat -6px 0;*/
}
#icons ul.nav1{
    height: 35px; /*added*/
}
#icons ul.nav1 li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 1px;
height: 35px !important; /*added*/ 
}
#icons ul.nav1 li a {
    display: inline;
    /*width: 34px;
    height: 31px;*/
}
ul.nav1 li a:hover {

}
#icons ul.nav1 li a#facebook {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
    background:url(/images/sprite_header_icons.png) no-repeat -6px 0; /*added*/
    width: 20px; /*added*/
    height: 35px; /*added*/
}
#icons ul.nav1 li a#twitter {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;   
    background:url(/images/sprite_header_icons.png) no-repeat -40px 0; /*added*/
    width: 20px; /*added*/
    height: 35px; /*added*/

}
#icons ul.nav1 li a#youtube {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
    background:url(/images/sprite_header_icons.png) no-repeat -74px 0; /*added*/
    width: 20px; /*added*/
    height: 35px; /*added*/
}
```

**NOTE:**

Okay, so i have made some changes based on what *Ryan Beaulieu*, *Alex Reynolds* & *OhMrBigshot* suggested here. Now, the tabs are clickable in IE (7/8)...however, the tabs are partially (li 38px x 16px) visible like this:

[image]

the width is fine, but **how can i increase the height to 35px from 16px?** Thank you!!

Comment: I could be wrong but it may be due to you have nothing in between the anchor tags

Comment: @Ryan, i hope that's not the case as I can't put anything between those tags...it's suppose to work just by clicking on different portion of the image

Comment: which version(s) of IE are you testing?

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu: looks like u were right...if i add something between the tags, i see that the mouse pointer changes to clickable "hand"....however, that messes up everything :(   but thanks for the idea :)  i'll keep playing w/ it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding display:block

```
#icons {
    position:absolute;
    top:44px;
    right:200px;
    z-index:9;
    float:left;
    width:210px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(/images/sprite_header_icons.png) no-repeat -6px 0;
}
#icons ul.nav1 li {
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
#icons ul.nav1 li a {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 31px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i tried what you suggested but that messes up the links even more as the links become block (the links are arranged vertically, they need to be horizontal)

Comment: ya I know it will mess up your icons you only had to re arrange if u have trouble i could help you but my question is, by using display:block fixed your problem? cuz i'm a fan of always using backgrounds instead of images inside my html and making them anchors and I never stumble with this kind of problem

Comment: yes, it actually fixed my problem (vertically) :) but as i'm not an expert at this, i wasn't sure how could i move the blocks to a inline position. So can/will you help me with that?

Comment: sure check this example http://jsfiddle.net/8qAhN/ I'm using same code you I just changed the css and obviously working with bgcolor cuz I don't have the link to your images

Answer (score 0):

Are you using rel="_blank"? Is that HTML5? Is the verision of IE you're using 9? Could it be that you should use target="_blank"?

Comment: hm...that's a very good point. i haven't tried w/ target="_blank" yet as W3C was giving me errors for using target="_blank". let me try it and will let you know if that's the case

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_rel.asp Not sure that this is causing your issue. Why not cut up your icon sprite and set the a.facebook background position 0 0 then a.twitter background position 40 0. This is probably the better way to lay it out. Same image sprite but you're trimming it for each anchor

Comment: okay, so i have tried `target="_blank"` and that's not the case unfortunately. i like your second idea, i was thinking about it this morning. BUT, i'm only the developer here, all the images are provided to me by another department and i'm **not** suppose to change anyone of them :(  i'll keep trying today and finally if i see i can't find any solutions then i'll ask my manager's permission to crop the icons.

Comment: No don't change the image. use it as a sprite but in each link tag in the css set the width and background to the icon in the sprite you want shown. ie ink 1 in css would get background:url(/images/sprite_header_icons.png) no-repeat -6px 0. Link 2 background:url(/images/sprite_header_icons.png) no-repeat -6px 34px; put a width property and you're links are no longer empty.

Comment: i have made some changes and it's kind of working now, but having another problem now. can you plz take a look at my modified post?

Answer (score 0):

IE sometimes ignores "empty" elements, even if you define size. Try adding `&nbsp;` in the `a` tag.

Comment: seems like this might be the main culprit :P  _Ryan Beaulieu_ first mentioned it and even though it messed up the links (if i click on FB icon then the Twitter page opens up, and if i click on Twitter tab then the YT page opens up)....i think if i play around w/ the padding/positions...it will fix my problem. I will let you know if it solves my problem. Thanks a lot for replying!